The account owner needs to set up a Google Payments merchant account before you can access this page

Completing this is necessary in order to use React Native for in-app purchases.How can I register for a Google Payments merchant account?Additionally, given I'm using React Native version 0.74.2, could you maybe outline the main stages for setting up IP and how to add money, coins, and coupons?
